# how to access a class's object by its name which is stored in a String?

Tags: class, dart, syntax

I would like to select an object in a class by its name stored in a variable. Is this feasible? So basically a syntax for the placeholder `-magic_syntax-` or any other method how this can be achieved.

```dart
const String kListNames = {'list1', 'list2'};

class MyClass {
  List<int> list1 = [0, 1, 2];
  List<bool> list2 = [true, false];
}

main() {
  List<dynamic> myList;
  MyClass myClass;
  for (var listName in kListNames) {
    myList = myClass.-magic_syntax-(listName);
  }
}
```

Comment: The only way to do that is to use `dart:mirrors`, because accessing by a name which is a run-time value is a kind of reflection. That library is only available on the stand-alone VM (not on the web, not in Flutter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart is a Compile time language. It's not possible to interact with variables through their variable names in the way you're suggesting.

why not store your data in a Map?

```dart
Map<String, List> myData = {
    'list1':  [0, 1, 2],
    'list2': [true, false],
}:

for(final listName in myData.keys) {
 ...
}
```

now you can loop over the data keys `myData.keys`, the values `myData.values` or both `myData.entries`

Comment: That is why I was hoping for some magic ;-) Anyhow, clever idea! I need to get my head around how to implement this. I have an ObjectBox DB with several lists. But I guess, I could transform this model into a map containing lists in my intermediate data model